# Can my landlord / building management reject pets?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, landlord, rent, pets

We asked our agent if he we could have a mature, well trained cat in the apartment that we rent. We know the cat already and he is fully litter trained and does not scratch ect.  He rejected by saying that it was against the building management - landlord contract - they have not provided any proof of this
Other animals live in the building - I understand that they may not have asked. 
There is no mention of pets in my contract which I initially took to mean that they are allowed and I was asking as a matter of curtesy to inform about the arrival of a pet.

Where do I stand? I have been in this flat for one and a half years and will be here for at least another year or two so do not want to upset the landlord - my agent is particularly useless and seems to not have a clue, to the point of requesting a visit only a few hours before he wants to arrive - no notice - and so I struggle to trust him.

Uk

Answer (score 3):

It is the terms of the lease that govern what you may and may not do, so if pets are not disallowed, they are allowed. You are not a party to the contract between the landlord and the agent, so whatever the landlord may have told the agent is technically irrelevant to you. However, this may be an indication that the landlord plans to change policy; it might also mean that the agent misunderstood something. That is where you stand legally.